# How To Call Only Specific Tag Slugs

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to call only specific tags in my WordPress `get_tags()` function. Right now they're displaying **ALL** tags instead of just the terms in the array. Even if the tag doesn't have a post I want the tag to show which is why `hide_empty => false` exists. I've been toying with this along with the codex but I feel like I'm accidentally canceling out what I'm trying to do. Guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php 
  $tags = get_tags(array(
    'taxonomy'  => 'post_tag',
    'hide_empty' => false, //want to show the tags called in the terms array even if they're empty
      'field'     => 'slug',
      'terms'     =>  array(
          'tag1',
          'tag2',
      ),
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your formatting is a little off. Below should return an array of tags that match your terms. The include argument requires a comma or space delimited list of ids.

You can also limit the objects it returns with the "fields" argument. See [get_tags()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags) for more info.

```
$tag1 = get_term_by("slug", "tag1", "post_tag");
$tag2 = get_term_by("slug", "tag2", "post_tag");

$tags_array = get_tags(array(
    "hide_empty" => false,
    "include" => "{$tag1->term_id},{$tag2->term_id}",
));
```